# First selection in Photoswipe gallery does not work

Tags: jquery-mobile, photoswipe

I am using Photoswipe gallery with jQuery Mobile. The first selection, when clicked/tapped shows just the image with full URL and does not work the gallery way. When I go back and select again, it works fine.

Can any one please tell me how can I sort this out?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

When user comes to photoswipe gallery page directly using link photoswipe is not initialized. For example even going to official demo using direct link renders this problem. Link: http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/04-jquery-mobile.html#Gallery1

Try putting script in which photoswipe attaches handlers for `pageshow` and `pagehide` events before `jquery-mobile.js`. If handlers are attached after they wont be triggered first time user visits page.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="code.photoswipe-3.0.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(window, $, PhotoSwipe){

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('div.gallery-page')
                .live('pageshow', function(e){
                    if( $('ul.gallery', e.target).length > 0 ){
                        var 
                            currentPage = $(e.target),
                            options = {},
                            photoSwipeInstance = $("ul.gallery a", e.target).photoSwipe(options,  currentPage.attr('id'));

                            return true;
                    }
                })

                .live('pagehide', function(e){
                    if( $('ul.gallery', e.target).length > 0 ){
                        var 
                            currentPage = $(e.target),
                            photoSwipeInstance = PhotoSwipe.getInstance(currentPage.attr('id'));

                        if (typeof photoSwipeInstance != "undefined" && photoSwipeInstance != null) {
                            PhotoSwipe.detatch(photoSwipeInstance);
                        }

                        return true;
                    }

                });

        });

    }(window, window.jQuery, window.Code.PhotoSwipe));

</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This works perfectly for me. Don't forget to adapt "div.gallery-page" and "ul.gallery".